# Why is Peppa a Pig?

Tags: animation, peppa-pig

Without any evidence, I wondered if Peppa was a pig to promote the idea of pigs as lovable pets rather than delicacies.

Regardless of whether that is true or false, I would like to know if the experts here have any information about the reason for choosing Peppa as a pig?

Comment: I would assume it has something to do with her parents both being pigs :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in this [long article at The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2019/may/16/how-peppa-pig-became-a-global-phenomenon-billion-pound):

> The family idea came first, and then the girl protagonist – another glaring gap in the market. **Next came the snorts, which, the animators hoped, children would enjoy copying in playgrounds. Snorts led naturally to pigs, and mud, and Peppa’s house on a hill.** “We gave her the red dress and the name, which is sort of hot and spicy, because we wanted her to be a bit edgy and have character,” Baker says.

Comment: A note on "hot and spicy" for any confused speakers of [rhotic English: most speakers in England are non-rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English#England), and would have "Peppa" and "Pepper" as homophones.